# Uncaught TypeError: Error resolving module specifier “axios”. Relative module specifiers must start with “./”, “../” or “/”. I didn't get the answer

Tags: javascript, import, parcel

I installed "npm install axios" and imported using "import axios from 'axios'.
I wanted to post the data and get the data

These are the codes I have used.

Package.json :

```
{
  "name": "ceniplex-tickets",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "ticket booking app",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Aswin Anilkumar",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "parcel": "^2.8.1",
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.8.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.2.1"
  }
}
```

JS code (Front end) :

```
import axios from 'axios';

class Model {
    constructor() {
        this.array = []
    }
    getArray() {
        return this.array;
    }

    async loadTicketsFromBackend() {
        const req = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/booking')
        const booking = req.data;

        console.log(booking);
    }

    async setArray(data) {
        const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/booking',data)
        return res;
    }
}

export default Model;
```

Comment: Here `import axios from 'axios'` you must give a relative path to `axios` module.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? Because I tried the same!

Comment: I don't know your directory structure, but you can read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#syntax), and write the correct path (not just the module name) instead of "module-name". Notice also what is said about filename extensions.